# Perl string concatenation overlaying strings

Tags: string, perl, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 3 strings in perl, and I am getting weird behavior.  The data was just written to a file previously in the script, and I am trying to add two columns to the data.

Here is my code and its behavior

```
print "phylipId is $phylipId\n";
print "Tree is $tree\n";
print "Line is $line\n";

my $string = join "\t", $phylipId, $tree, $line;

print "Concatenated is $string\n";
```

Gives me this output

```
phylipId is 4
Tree is (138,((139,141),140));
Line is 000931  17.0    1.0 0.135   no  1044    646918204
Concaten000931s 17.0    1.08,((10.1351),no0));  1044    646918204
```

This also happened when I used the . operator.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like youre reading `$tree` from a file using carriage-returns (`\r`), and `$tree` is ending up with `\r` at the end of it causing it to seek to the beginning of the line.

See this test:

```
perl -e 'print("abcdefghijkl\r\t012\n");'
```

Which outputs

```
abcdefgh012l
```

Comment: Yeah, this was the problem.  I was generating the tree files using a template file that had been created in windows.  I fixed the line endings for them and it works now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As patrick says, it is more than likely you have read a DOS-formatted file on a Linux box. In those circumstances, if you use `chomp` on a string terminated with `"\r\n"` you will be left with the `"\r"`.

The simplest way to clean up records like this is to replace `chomp` with

```
s/\s+$//
```

which, since both `"\r"` and `"\n"` count as whitespace, will remove both from the string simultaneously. If trailing tabs and spaces are important for you then use

```
s/[\r\n]+$//
```

instead, or perhaps

```
s/[[:cntrl:]]+$//
```

or

```
s/\p{Control}+$//
```

Comment: If the file is known to have "\r\n" line endings, the clean way to so this is to set `$/ = "\r\n"` and then use chomp.

Comment: @Patrick: My intention was to offer something that would work on all files regardless of origin, but you are absolutely right and that is what I would write.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate your issue after trying under Windows and Linux.

- Could the issue be related to how your console is configured?
- does it happen on other machines too?
- Can you tell more about your exact environment?
- What happens if you try to print that line to a text file instead of stdout?